# System Service to Monitor a folder

Tags: services, yocto

I am developing an embedded Linux image. I currently have a `udev` rule to monitor for USB attach/detach events. If a USB is attached a script is run to search the device for an `upgrade.sh` script.

I now want to expand this to monitor a folder on the system. If a file is added to this folder I want to run a shell script.

I am unsure where to start, is this another `udev` rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to setup is a [systemd `path` unit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.path.html) along with an associated service. The two unit files could look as follows:

1. Path specification `watch-folder.path`. In this example, we use the `PathChanged` directive to check if any write operation to the path was completed (you can also use this to watch a specific file, if you want).

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=Systemd unit to watch a folder for new files

   [Path]
   PathChanged=/path/to/folder/you/want/to/monitor/

   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
   ```
2. The service, which will call your script, needs to have the same name (except for the extension): `watch-folder.service`

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=Systemd service to process changes to a watched folder

   [Service]
   Type=oneshot
   ExecStart=/path/to/shellscript.sh
   ```

   Note that the shell script will not receive any argument, so it needs to know the path to the monitored folder by itself (hardcoded).

Copy the files to the appropriate directory (e.g. `/etc/systemd/system`) and enable the **path** (not the service!) via

```
systemctl enable watch-folder.path
```

Then, start path monitoring via

```
systemctl start watch-folder.path
```